# Laravel has_many. Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel (and OOP) and I'm putting together a store. I have put together a relationship for my product images, it works as I need it to but I just wanted to check that I'm doing it correctly/efficiently. If anyone experienced with Laravel could cast their eye over the below and suggest improvements or give me some feedback, it would be greatly appreciated.

I have products which have many product images. Here are my models for product and productimage:

Product:

```
class Products extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'core_Products';
    ........
    public function ProductImages(){
        return $this->has_many('ProductImage', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Productimage:

```
class ProductImage extends Eloquent{

    public static $table = 'core_productimages';

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongs_to('Product');
    }
}
```

My product controller (this is where I am thinking I could be doing things more efficiently. Surely I shouldn't need to be passing the product_id to retrieve the images. Shouldn't the model already be aware of this?):

```
class Store_Product_Controller extends Base_Controller {

public function action_index($serfURL = "", $intSectionID, $pSerfURL = "", $intProductID)
{

            .......
    $view->productImages = Products::find($intProductID)->ProductImages()->get();

    return $view;       


    }

}
```

and finally, my view:

```
foreach ($productImages as $image){
    echo $image->strImageURI . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Not an answer i know - but you are probably best targetting this at the Laravel community - www.laravel.io ;-)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, just thinking that you don't need `->get()` because `has_many` is already returning array of images. cmiiw

Comment: Unless its a typo, your model should be a singular i.e. `Product` The view I would look at using the power of the blade templating solution, but what you have seems good. The last thing I would say is look at using RESTful controllers, it makes more sense to me. That's my $0.02 :)

Comment: Postng your database model would be useful too. there is also [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

In your Products model you could instead call your method `images()` so that in your controller you can just call `->images()` on your product. Also, your model should be singular and there is no need for the `'product_id'` on your has_many query as it is assumed. It would look something like this:

Product Model:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'core_Products';

    // ...

    public function images() {

        return $this->has_many('ProductImage');
    }
}
```

ProductImage Model:

```
class ProductImage extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'core_productimages';

    public function product() {

        return $this->belongs_to('Product');
    }
}
```

Product Controller:

```
class Store_Product_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public function action_index($serfURL = "", $intSectionID, $pSerfURL = "", $intProductID) {

        // ...

        $view->product = Product::find($intProductID);

        return $view;       
    }

}
```

Product View:

```
foreach ($product->images as $image) {

    echo $image->strImageURI . "<br/>";
}
```